# chart no plotting

Tags: android, sqlite, bar-chart, achartengine

I have written the following code to plot a graph but it is not plotting and i haven't got any errors.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong. I am trying to create a bar chart by taking the values from a database.

```
package flu.solutions.travelsense;


import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Color;
public class ChartActivity<BMICalculatorDB> extends Activity{

    public ChartActivity() {
        super();
    }
        //public ChartActivity(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            //int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        //super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //}


        public static final String KEY_BMIID = "bmi_id";
        public static final String KEY_BMIDATA = "bmi_data";
        public static final String KEY_BMIDATE = "bmi_date";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Jayant";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "android_metadata";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        private DBHelper ourHelper;
        private static Context ourContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

        private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

            public DBHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_BMIID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_BMIDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_BMIDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
                        );
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE );
                onCreate(db);
            }

        }

        public void BMICalculatorDB(Context c){
            ourContext = c;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public BMICalculatorDB open(){
            ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return (BMICalculatorDB) this;
        }

        public void close(){
            ourHelper.close();
        }

        public long createEntry( String data, String date ) {
            //, String date 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_BMIDATA, data);
            cv.put(KEY_BMIDATE, date);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }

        public String getBMIID() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] column =
                    new String[]{ KEY_BMIID };
            Cursor c = 
                    ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null);

            String result = "";
            int iID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BMIID);

            for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
                result = result + c.getString(iID);
            }

            return result;
        }

        public String getBMIDataData(){

            String[] column =
                        new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATA };
                Cursor c = 
                        ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

                String result = "";
                int iData = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_BMIDATA );

                for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
                    result = result + c.getString( iData );
                }


            return result;
        }

        public String getBMIDateData(){
            String[] column =
                    new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATE };
            Cursor c = 
                    ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

            String result = "";
            int iDate = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_BMIDATE);

            for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
                result = result + c.getString( iDate );
            }


        return result;
        }

        public void updateEntry( long lId, String mData, String mDate ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();

            cvUpdate.put( KEY_BMIDATA, mData );
            cvUpdate.put( KEY_BMIDATE, mDate );
            ourDatabase.update( DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_BMIID + " = lId", null );
        }

        public String getData(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public String getDate(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset(String title) {

            String[] column =
                    new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATA };
            Cursor c = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase().query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

            TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Bar1");
            TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries(title);

            getBMIDataData();

            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                int date = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DAYS"));
                int weight = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOP 10"));
                series2.add(weight, date);
                c.moveToNext();
            }

            c.close();

            dataset.addSeries(series);
            dataset.addSeries(series2);

            return dataset;
        }


        public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

            //Lager TimeSeries for den første linja
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = getDemoDataset("Bar1");

            //Kode for render
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

            //Optimalisering linje1
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            renderer.setFillPoints(true);

            // Optimalisering linje2 husk rekke følgen
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
            renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

            //Legger til render seriene
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

            //Optimalisering grafen
            mRenderer.setChartTitle("Test");
            mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
            mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
            mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            mRenderer.setXTitle("Dager");
            mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);


            Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, 
                    mRenderer, "Bar Graph Title");

            return intent;

        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Edited code.

```
package flu.solutions.travelsense;

import java.util.List;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String KEY_Primary1 = "pri_id";
    public static final String KEY_Primary2 = "pri_data";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Jayant";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "android_data";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    String[] titles = new String[] { "Average Booking Value of Transactions Across Time", " " };


    private DBHelper ourHelper;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_Primary1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_Primary2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "                 
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void open() {
        ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public long createEntry( String data, String date ) {
        //, String date 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_Primary2, data);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getBMIID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_Primary1 };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null);

        String result = "";
        int iID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Primary1);

        for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString(iID);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String getBMIDataData(){

        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_Primary2 };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

        String result = "";
        int iData = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_Primary2 );

        for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString( iData );
        }
        return result;
    }



    public void updateEntry( long lId, String mData, String mDate ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();

        cvUpdate.put( KEY_Primary2, mData );
        ourDatabase.update( DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_Primary1 + " = lId", null );
    }

    public String getData(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String getDate(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset(String title) {

        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_Primary2 };
        Cursor c = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase().query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Bar1");
        TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries(title);

        getBMIDataData();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            int date = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DAYS"));
            int weight = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOP 10"));
            series2.add(weight, date);
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        c.close();

        dataset.addSeries(series);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);

        return dataset;
    }

    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

         int[] colors = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.BLACK};

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
            renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

            setChartSettings(renderer, "Average Booking Value of Transactions Across Time", " ", " ", 0,10, 0,10, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

            renderer.setXLabels(1);
            renderer.setYLabels(10);

            int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
              SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
              seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
              }

            return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, DATABASE_TABLE), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
            }

            protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
            {

            // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

                XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

                renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);

                renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);

                renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);

                renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

                int length = colors.length;

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
                {
                  SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                  r.setColor(colors[i]);
                  renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
                }
                return renderer;
              }

               protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
               String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
              {

              // sets lots of default values for this renderer

               renderer.setChartTitle(title);

               renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
               renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

               renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
               renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);

               renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
               renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);

               renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
               renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

               renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
               renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

               renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f);

            }

            protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, String databaseTable) 
            {

                // adds the axis titles and values into the dataset

                XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                int length = titles.length;

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
                {
                  CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
                  double[] v = databaseTable.get(i);
                  int seriesLength = v.length;
                  for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
                  {
                    series.add(v[k]);
                  }

                  dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
                 }
                return dataset;
                }

            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_chart, menu);
                return true;
            }



        //Lager TimeSeries for den første linja
        }
```

Hi i have edited the above code but i am still facing errors can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one class:

```
public class ChartActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
        db.open();
        Intent intent = db.getIntent(this);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and this is another:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String KEY_BMIID = "bmi_id";
    public static final String KEY_BMIDATA = "bmi_data";
    public static final String KEY_BMIDATE = "bmi_date";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Jayant";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "android_metadata";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBHelper ourHelper;
    private Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_BMIID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_BMIDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_BMIDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void open() {
        ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public long createEntry( String data, String date ) {
        //, String date 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_BMIDATA, data);
        cv.put(KEY_BMIDATE, date);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getBMIID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_BMIID };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null);

        String result = "";
        int iID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BMIID);

        for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString(iID);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String getBMIDataData(){

        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATA };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

        String result = "";
        int iData = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_BMIDATA );

        for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString( iData );
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getBMIDateData(){
        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATE };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

        String result = "";
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_BMIDATE);

        for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString( iDate );
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void updateEntry( long lId, String mData, String mDate ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();

        cvUpdate.put( KEY_BMIDATA, mData );
        cvUpdate.put( KEY_BMIDATE, mDate );
        ourDatabase.update( DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_BMIID + " = lId", null );
    }

    public String getData(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String getDate(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset(String title) {

        String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATA };
        Cursor c = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase().query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Bar1");
        TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries(title);

        getBMIDataData();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            int date = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DAYS"));
            int weight = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOP 10"));
            series2.add(weight, date);
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        c.close();

        dataset.addSeries(series);
        dataset.addSeries(series2);

        return dataset;
    }

    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        //Lager TimeSeries for den første linja
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = getDemoDataset("Bar1");

        //Kode for render
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        //Optimalisering linje1
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // Optimalisering linje2 husk rekke følgen
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

        //Legger til render seriene
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        //Optimalisering grafen
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Test");
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setXTitle("Dager");
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);

        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, 
                mRenderer, "Bar Graph Title");

        return intent;
    }
}
```

this will give you a line chart and not a bar graph. the culprit is:
Intent intent = ChartFactory.**getLineChartIntent**(context...
among other things, you need to doctor much more of this code for your own specifications.